# Awk conditional filter one file based on another (or other solutions)

Tags: file, filter, awk, conditional-statements

Programming beginner here needs some help modifying an AWK script to make it conditional. Alternative non-awk solutions are also very welcome.

**NOTE** Main filtering is now working thanks to help from Birei but I have an additional problem, see note below in question for details.

I have a series of input files with 3 columns like so:

```
chr4    190499999   190999999
chr6    61999999    62499999
chr1    145499999   145999999
```

I want to use these rows to filter another file (refGene.txt) and if a row in file one mathces a row in refGene.txt, to output column 13 in refGene.txt to a new file 'ListofGenes_$f'.
The tricky part for me is that I want it to count as a match as long as column one (eg 'chr4', 'chr6', 'chr1' ) and column 2 AND/OR column 3 matches the equivalent columns in the refGene.txt file. The equivalent columns between the two files are $1=$3, $2=$5, $3=$6.
Then I am not sure in awk how to not print the whole row from refGene.txt but only column 13.

**NOTE** I have achieved the conditional filtering described above thanks to help from Birei. Now I need to incorporate an additional filter condition. I also need to output column $13 from the refGene.txt file if any of the region between value $2 and $3 overlaps with the region between $5 and $6 in the refGene.txt file. This seems a lot trickier as it involves mathmatical computation to see if the regions overlap.

My script so far:

```
FILES=/files/*txt   
for f in $FILES ;
do

    awk '
        BEGIN {
            FS = "\t";
        }
        FILENAME == ARGV[1] {
            pair[ $1, $2, $3 ] = 1;
            next;
        }
        {
            if ( pair[ $3, $5, $6 ] == 1 ) {
                print $13;
            }
        }
    ' $(basename $f) /files/refGene.txt > /files/results/$(basename $f) ;
done
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks so much!

Rubal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way.

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = "\t"; }

    ## Save third, fifth and seventh field of first file in arguments (refGene.txt) as the key
    ## to compare later. As value the field to print.
    FNR == NR {
        pair[ $3, $5, $6 ] = $13;
        next;
    }

    ## Set the name of the output file.
    FNR == 1 {
        output_file = "";
        split( ARGV[ARGIND], path, /\// );
        for ( i = 1; i < length( path ); i++ ) {
            current_file = ( output_file ? "/" : "" ) path[i];
        }
        output_file = output_file "/ListOfGenes_" path[i];
    }

    ## If $1 = $3, $2 = $5 and $3 = $6, print $13 to output file.
    {
        if ( pair[ $1, $2, $3 ] ) {
            print pair[ $1, $2, $3 ] >output_file;
        }
    }
' refGene.txt /files/rubal/*.txt
```

Comment: @user964689: I missunderstood the question at first sight. I've edited the answer. I don't fully understand exactly how you want to compare fields, but code is commented so it shouldn't be too difficult to modify if result is near to the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Works great thanks, though i realised I have to add an additional requirement that makes it more complicated. I have edited the question to reflect this. If you can help with that it would be fantastic. Thanks.