# How to get common lines between two files using awk

Tags: awk

I have two files which have some lines in common.

file1 have values separated by ";"

```
20160301 000000;0.713290;0
20160301 000001;0.713270;0
20160301 000003;0.713280;0
20160301 000005;0.713270;0
20160301 000006;0.713280;0
20160301 000010;0.713250;0
20160301 000011;0.713260;0
20160301 000012;0.713260;0
20160301 000013;0.713260;0
...
```

file2:

```
20160301 000000  
20160301 000001  
20160301 000003
```

Desired output:

```
20160301 000000;0.713290;0
20160301 000001;0.713270;0
20160301 000003;0.713280;0
```

i've tried `grep -f` but i took long time to perform since the both files (file1 & file 2)are huge.
i'm looking for an alternative using `awk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $1 in a' file2 file1
```

Given your new input where file2 lines can have trailing blank chars:

```
$ tr ' ' '#' < file1
20160301#000000;0.713290;0
20160301#000001;0.713270;0
20160301#000003;0.713280;0
20160301#000005;0.713270;0
20160301#000006;0.713280;0
20160301#000010;0.713250;0
20160301#000011;0.713260;0
20160301#000012;0.713260;0
20160301#000013;0.713260;0
...

$ tr ' ' '#' < file2
20160301#000000##
20160301#000001##
20160301#000003

$ awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{sub(/ +$/,""); a[$0];next} $1 in a' file2 file1
20160301 000000;0.713290;0
20160301 000001;0.713270;0
20160301 000003;0.713280;0
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but didn't work, may be i forgot to mention that my fisrt column is actualy not 1,2,3 but it's 1 1, 1 2, 1 3. (first column contain spaces).

Comment: yes it' didn't work, ,the output file is empty. Sorry i just mention that my first column isn't as the description (i edit my question).

Answer (score 1):

If your files are already sorted in the key field (as in your case)

```
$ join -t';' file1 file2
1 1;adc;01
2 2;efg;02
3 3;hij;03
```

this is the typical use case for `join` command.  If not sorted you can pass sorted outputs

```
$ $ join -t';' <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1];next}$1 in A' file2 file1
```

This is untested and I am on my cell so I apologize if this is not what you want :)

Comment: thanks for the answer but didn't work, may be i forgot to mention that my fisrt column is actualy not 1,2,3 but it's 1 1, 1 2, 1 3. (first column contain spaces)

Comment: A solution hsa already been posted **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730800/awk-matching-between-two-files-when-regions-intersect-any-solutions-welcome**

Comment: @ArifBurhan that Q/A is much more complicated and has very little to do with this Q/A except that it involves 2 files.