# Identify overlapping ranges in AWK

Tags: file, text, awk, comparison, match

I have a file with rows of 3 columns (tab separated) eg:

```
2 45 100
```

And a second file with rows of 3 columns (tab separated) eg:

```
2 10 200
```

I want an awk command that matched the lines if $1 in both files matches and the range between $2-$3 in file one interstects at all with the range in $2-$3 in file 2. It can be within the range of values in file 2 or the range in file 2 can be within the range in file 1, or theer can just be a partial overlap. Any kind of intersect between the ranges would count as a match and then print the row in file 3.

My current code only matches if $1 and either $2 or $3 match, but doesn't work for when the ranges are within each other as in these cases the precise numbers don't match.

```
  awk '
        BEGIN {
            FS = "\t";
        }
        FILENAME == ARGV[1] {
            pair[ $1, $2, $3 ] = 1;
            next;
        }
        {
            if ( pair[ $1, $2, $3 ] == 1 ) {
                print $1 $2 $3;
            }
        }
```

Example Input:

File1:

```
1 10 23
2 30 50
6 100 110
8 20 25
```

File2:

```
1 5 15
10 30 50
2 10 100
8 22 24
```

Here line 1(file1) matches line 1(file2) because the first column matches AND range 10-15 overlaps between both ranges
Line 2 (file1) matches line 3(file2) because first column matches and range of 30-50 is within range 10-100.
Line 4(file1) matches line 4(file2) because first column matches and the range 22-24 overlaps in both.
Therefore output would be lines 1,2 and 4 from file2 printed in a new output file.

Hope these examples help.

Your help is really appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've tried to help you with this problem before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727108/awk-conditional-filter-one-file-based-on-another-or-other-solutions). I suggest you to provide an example of your input and the expected output. Otherwise you are forcing all us to guess and build our own tests that won't be as accurate of what you could provide us. It's time and effort loss for those who wish to help you.

Comment: thanks i didn't realise you'd updated the answer to deal with the overlapping ranges problem. Ill take a look and if it works Ill close this question. I added examples as requested above.

Comment: No. I didn't update it. But the other thread was more complex because you asked to go throught a folder looking for files and process each one of them. I had to create all those files with my own (guessed) data and was much more work than expected at first sight.

Comment: I got it, but what is the expected output?

Comment: I see, well I figured out how to put the awk command into a loop 'for f in folder' etc so should be ok now as long as there is an awk command that works for a single file1 compared to file2 then I will integrate it into a loop. I appreciate your help, your first solution worked for many files. This additional question is actually for a slightly different dataset where the regions in file1 are much smaller so I miss overlaps where the range in file1 is within the range in file2 which never happened in the first dataset. So thanks your efforts have already helped.

Comment: expected output is a list of the matching rows from file 2, so in the above example it would be lines 1,2 and 4 printed in a new output file

Comment: I added your expected output to my answer in first place. I hope it is fine for you ;-)

Comment: @user964689: I hope you understand me, it's only a recommendation. Users that provide accurate input data and expected output, besides it's own approach to a solution, usually they get better answers. In your other thread I tried to help you to solve the same problem with ranges but struggled because I had no data to test it and left the problem feeling a bit frustrated. That is at least one answer lost because you didn't give a full specification of your problem, and there could be more similar cases like mine.

Comment: sure I understand and appreciate your comments so that I can make better questions in the future. Sorry you felt frustrated as your answer worked and has been helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy if you use `join` command to merge both files by its first field ($1):

If you only want the file2 lines as output:

```
join --nocheck-order <(sort -n file1) <(sort -n file2) | awk '{if ($2 >= $4 && $2 <= $5 || $3 >= $4 && $3 <= $5 || $4 >= $2 && $4 <= $3 || $5 >= $2 && $5 <= $3) {print $1" "$4" "$5;}}' -
```

Using your input files I got this output:

```
1 5 15
2 10 100
8 22 24
```

Comment: I edited my answer and I added your desired output in first place.

Comment: Thanks this might be helpful but I need the output as the lines that match in line 2 on their own, as this information will be used later for referencing with a 3rd file (a separate task not shown here. Also the 2nd file has some additional information fields not shown here because they aren't needed in the overlap. Sorry for not specifying it before, I was trying to keep the question as straightforward as possible.

Comment: I removed other cases. If you have more parameters in each file, just add more $... to the print line. Be careful because $ values used in `if` statement may change. But it works

Comment: great I also want to use this for some data where file 2 has different column numbers for the corresponding data. eg file1 $1=$3 in file2, file1 $2=$5 in file2 and file1 $3=$6 in file2. I don't totally comprehend your script so can you show me which $ values to replace to that would work? Then that's everything thanks so much

Comment: If each line in file1 has the same number of fields it is quite easy. To understand my code I recommend you to execute `join file1 file2` and you will understand the if statement in awk.

Comment: Then it works for you. What you only have to add is a `for loop` from 4 to NF because of the variable length of file2

Comment: NF?  I tried looking this up, but couldnt find a definition in awk help or google search.

Comment: I made a version of file2 with only the columns that match file 1. So there are some cases that do not match. eg chr12 6074855 6077586 in file 1 is not matching with chr12 5928300 6104097 in file 2. Is this unexpected?

Comment: I should clarify, I mean that is an example that should match but doesn't and I was wondering if you think that your script should be catching such cases. I get this error after the name of the second file: :1726: is not sorted:   I ran sort on the file first, is there anything else I should do? It still runs but maybe this is causing problems

Comment: Looking at the joined file it seems all the values that are joined rom file2 are very large and the smaller values are not being joined. It's also missing some of the values from file1 completely, so seems to be a problem with the join function

Comment: are both files sorted by their first field?? Join's input should be sorted. Tell me if it is, else we can solve it.

Comment: removed the 'chr' part of $1 and sorted them numerically -n -k 1 before join but I still get sorting errors. Not sure why they look sorted

Comment: The error for one of the files is here:=
Y 9975488 9978285
1 100088227 100162167
 It tells me the line starting with 1 is unsorted, its the first line with a numerical first column. Also in other file the results are sorted in reverse numerical in first column despite using teh same sort command. very confused.

Comment: yes using `join --nocheck-order <(sort -n file1) <(sort -n file2)` works